# Jquery UI setter error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a Jquery - UI slider like this

the HTML

```
<div id="slider1" class="slider"></div>
```

I am trying to set the slider value using the UI setter values

```
var value = data.listing.price;   // Setting slider value

    var slide = document.getElementById("slider1");
    slide.slider( "value" , value );
```

on Chrome I get the following error

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'slider'

I am not sure what the error is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slide` truly does not have a `slider` method because `.slider` is a part of jQuery-ui. And you have not created any jquery objects.

Change:

```
var slide = document.getElementById("slider1");
```

To:

```
var slide = $("#slider1");
```

Comment: No worries. Its a good thing getElementById rote for you, instead of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

you use the DOM object not the jquery object, try this `$(slide).slider( "value" , value );`